# EJB Schedule automatic start on weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I currently have an EJB that has an @ schedule that runs every 5 minutes, but I only run after the ejb initialized.

the question is whether you can make the timer starts running after deployment and do not wait until there is an invocation to the EJB for starting.

Here is my code:

```
@Remote(ServiceRemote.class)
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/ServiceEJBSL")
public class ServiceBean implements ServiceRemote {
@Schedule(second="*", minute="*/5", hour="*", dayOfWeek="0-6")
public void autmaticTimer() throws Exception, RemoteException{
System.out.println("do something");
}
}
```

I did this in glasfish server but it seems doesnt work the same way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need **GlassFish v3.+** because this feature was added in **EJB 3.1**

> Automatic timers are created by the EJB container when an enterprise
>   bean that contains methods annotated with the `@Schedule` or
>   `@Schedules` annotations is deployed.

```
@Schedule(minute="*/5", hour="*")
public void automaticTimer() throws Exception, RemoteException{
   System.out.println("do something");
}
```

*Addition*

Try to add

```
@Schedule(minute="*/5", hour="*", persistent=false)
```

Because persistent timers are not re-created if already existing when `keepstate` is set to `true`.

See

- [**Automatic Timers**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Comment: Hello Alexey, thanks 4 the answer, im using weblogic server 11g... does this version support ejb 3.1?

Comment: Many thanks Alexey, another question, im using Glassfish 3.0.1 (build 22) with another project and this code works perfectly, so, do u know what specification of Java ee is glassfish using? Thanks a lot for your help!